# SQL isn't updating when I give them ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

Can someone tell me why this isn't updating? The id exists in the table but it wont update.

```
    let sql = `UPDATE Users
                SET MMR = MMR-30, Lose = Lose+1
                WHERE Nameid = ${data[0].Team1id}`;
   db.run(sql, data, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log(`Row(s) updated: ${this.changes}`);
        });
```

But it updates when I edit to this, but I need it to work with Nameid. Because if the team1 changes its name it wont find itself in the table! Meanwhile you cant change your id.

```
    let sql = `UPDATE Users
                SET MMR = MMR-30, Lose = Lose+1
                WHERE Name = "${data[0].Team1name}"`;  // this was changed
   db.run(sql, data, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log(`Row(s) updated: ${this.changes}`);
        });
```

Got it! Im gonna leave it here if someone stumbles with the same problem someday!

```
     let sql1 = `UPDATE Users
                SET MMR = MMR+25, Win= Win+1
                WHERE Nameid = ?`;
    db.run(sql1, data[0].Team1id, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
      console.log(`Row(s) updated: ${this.changes}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `console.log()` the `data[0].Team1id` and see what it gives,
I really can't see any problem in the code, just that `team1id` could be incorrect.

---

Another thing...

You need to secure the SQL, it's vulnerable for SQL Injection. Search for "node.js secure for MySQL injection".

Comment: Im getting this returned from the console log: 80267260358295550. Which is actually a ID that exists in the table. I will search for the sql injection! thanks.
Still can't see why it aint updating...

Comment: in the second query you do "${data[0].Team1name}"

Comment: and in the first you don't use - " -, try that it's can be the problem

Comment: Tried that, still the same. I'm cracking my head over this cant find the reason why it wont update

Comment: NameId is part of the table? if it's not i'm really sorry, i never use SQL like that :\

Comment: Yeah it is, Users (Name TEXT, Nameid int, MMR int, Win int, Lose int). Well atleast you tried! Thanks, I hope I can figure it out :)

Comment: Got it,  editted it in my original post! Dont know why it works that way and not the way around!